# Wrap All Image Tags In A String With Links

Tags: php

Trying to automatically wrap all image tags within a field that's currently managed with CKEditor.  Would really like to handle it all with PHP.

So this would be an example of a field's random contents:

```
<p>
    Intro text here<br />
    <img alt="sample desc" src="/images/example1.jpg" />
    Long article text here...
    <img alt="sample desc" src="/images/example2.jpg" />
    Short article text here...
    <img alt="sample desc" src="/images/example3.jpg" />
</p>
```

And I would need to change the above code to this, wrapping each image tag with a link using a unique id, href matching the img's source and title matching alt text:

```
<p>
    Intro text here<br />
    <a id="image1" href="/images/example1.jpg" title="sample desc">
       <img alt="sample desc" src="/images/example1.jpg" />
    </a>
    Long article text here...
    <a id="image2" href="/images/example2.jpg" title="sample desc">
       <img alt="sample desc" src="/images/example2.jpg" />
    </a>
    Short article text here...
    <a id="image3" href="/images/example3.jpg" title="sample desc">
       <img alt="sample desc" src="/images/example3.jpg" />
    </a>
</p>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's arbitrary HTML that comes from external sources then it's most simple with e.g. [querypath](/questions/tagged/querypath)

```
$html = htmlqp($html);
foreach ($html->find("img") as $img) {
    $img->wrap("<a href='{$img->attr('src')}'></a>");
}
print $html->top("p")->html();
```

You might want to inject `id=` and `title=` likewise in the loop, but that's about it.

Comment: How would I make the id unique for each image using QueryPath?

Comment: You do need a counter. Then add `$id_conter++;` in the loop, and `id='image$id_counter'` within the wrap string.

Comment: How should this be edited to work with multiple paragraph tags in the field?

Comment: http://api.querypath.org/docs/class_query_path.html - You probably mean `print $html->top("body")->innerHtml();`

Comment: Thanks a lot mario. This will definitely accomplish my goal. Just need to learn more about QueryPath now :)

Answer (score 0):

Give an id to the p..lets say main_p in order to select it..or you can choose any other selector..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i=1;
        $("#main_p img").each(function(){
$(this).wrap('<a id=image'+i+++' href='+$(this).attr("src")+' title="sample desc"/>');
})
});
```

This will make exectly what code you have writtten second..

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cgDyz/)

Comment: Thanks Rajat. I'm really trying to stick with server-side on this one.