# PHP - 'wrap' <a> tag around any <img> tag within a string

Tags: php, preg-replace, domdocument

I need to take any img tag within a string, and add an a tag around it.

E.g.

```
$content= "Click for more info <img src="\http://www.domain.com/1.jpg\"" />";
```

Would need to be replaced with

```
"Click for more info <a href=\"http://www.domain.com/1.jpg\"<img src="\http://www.domain.com/1.jpg\"" /></a>";
```

My current script is:

```
$content = $row_rsGetStudy['content'];

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content);
$imageTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach($imageTags as $tag) {
    $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "<a href=\"$tag\"><img src=\"$tag\" /></a>", $content); 
}

echo $content
```

This gives me the following error: 
Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: in your script $content is an object and preg_replace supports string and arrays only.

Answer (score 2):

With DOM methods, something like this (untested, debug yourself ;P )

```
foreach($imageTags as $tag) {
    $a = $tag->ownerDocument->createElement('a');
    $added_a = $tag->parentNode->insertBefore($a,$tag);
    $added_a->setAttribute('href',$tag->getAttribute('src'));
    $added_a->appendChild($tag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$content is an object which can not be converted to string.
to test it, use `var_dump($content);`
you can't directly echo it.
use properties and methods which offer by DOM, you can get from here: [DOM Elements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php)

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName` returns DOMNodeList object containing all the matched elements. So $tag is DOMNodelist::item here and hence can't be used directly in string operations. You need to get `nodeValue`. Change the foreach code as follows:

```
foreach($imageTags as $tag) {
    $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "<a href=\"$tag->nodeValue\"><img src=\"$tag->nodeValue\" /></a>", $content); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here the DOMDocument is not loading HTML from the string. Some strange issue. I prefer you to use DOM parser such as [SimpleHTML](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

You can use it like :

```
  $content= 'Click for more info <img src="http://www.domain.com/1.jpg" />';

  require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

  $post_dom = str_get_html($content);

  $img_tags = $post_dom->find('img');

  $images = array();

  foreach($img_tags as $image) {
      $source = $image->attr['src'];
      $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "<a href=\"$source\"><img src=\"$source\" /></a>", $content); 
 }

 echo $content;
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Better approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871356/wrap-all-image-tags-in-a-string-with-links